# Sending Multi part Form file

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, blazor, blazor-server-side

hello everyone I'm facing an issue when sending this post request this exception is being raised at sending line of code: The stream was already consumed. It cannot be read again.

```
public async Task<UploadResult> UploadProductImage(IBrowserFile file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                // Add the file to the content
                using (Stream s = file.OpenReadStream())
                {
                    var streamContent = new StreamContent(s);

                    streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);
                    content.Add(streamContent, "file", file.Name);

                    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("product-images", content);// here...............

                    // Process the response
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // Handle success
                        return null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Handle error
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample code;

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage ImportFile()
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var filePath = string.Empty;
        HttpPostedFile postedFile = null;
        foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
        {
            postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
            filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/" + postedFile.FileName);                
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
     }
```

Then read file from file path.

I hope it helps.